# What is the name of the thing that has the same definition as *section* except continuity?

Tags: terminology, fiber-bundles

The [definition of *section*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(fiber_bundle)) is this:

> In the mathematical field of topology, a **section** (or **cross
>   section**) is a continuous right inverse of the projection function
>   $\pi$. In other words, if $E$  is a fiber bundle over a base space,
>   $B$:
>
> $\pi : E \to B$
>
> then a section of that fiber bundle is a continuous map,
>
> $\sigma: B \to E$
>
> such that
>
> $\pi(\sigma(x)) = x$ for all $x \in B$.

Is there a name for the oject that are defined so, that we omit the continuity from the definition of the section?  In other words, I am looking for a correct (standard) replacement word for (what) here:

> In the mathematical field of topology, a **(what)** is a right inverse of the projection function
>   $\pi$. In other words, if $E$  is a fiber bundle over a base space,
>   $B$:
>
> $\pi : E \to B$
>
> then a (what) of that fiber bundle is a map,
>
> $\sigma: B \to E$
>
> such that
>
> $\pi(\sigma(x)) = x$ for all $x \in B$.

**Motivation**: I'd like to find a standard name for the set of the points in the 3-dimensional space that correspond to the points of a given photo. Here the fibers are the 1-dimensional subspaces (or cones) of the physical space, and the base space is the photo itself. In general, it isn't a section because of the possible lack of continuity.

Comment: It's just a right inverse. This works in any category. A continuous right inverse is a section, as you say. A selector for $\pi$ would be a reasonable name too, as we "select" a point in each fibre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lee (in “Introduction to Smooth Manifolds“) calls these maps  “rough sections“ to stress the difference from continuous or even smooth sections.

Answer (score 3):

You could call it a "right inverse to the projection", a "set-theoretic section", or a "possibly discontinuous section".  If you want a brief term, I would recommend simply saying "section" and mentioning once that you do not assume sections are continuous.  Indeed, it is not really universally standard to assume that sections are continuous; rather, "section" is used as a shorthand for "continuous section" much the same way "map" is used as a shorthand for "continuous map".

Comment: Also the phrase "not-necessarily continuous section" conveys the right idea.

Answer (score 2):

These are called any/all of:

- Set-theoretic sections
- Sections in the category of sets
- Sections in $\mathbf{Set}$
- Sections with respect to the category structure on the groupoid of topological manifold in which morphisms are functions.
- etc.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28category_theory%29) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I already heard the word lift or lifting for this, similarly to [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lift.html)